# Operation must use an updateable query Error when deploy on a server

Tags: ms-access, oledb

Hi I have a web application and I am using MS Access 2003 for my web database. My Database file is located in the App_Data folder. I am using this database file to insert and populate data to my web page. Both of this scenario insert, delete and select statement works fine on my PC. But whenever I tried to do the same thing where I hosted my web application only select statement would work. Insert or delete won't work, it shows an error message "Operation must use an updateable query". I am not sure why? I am still a newbie. Can you help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you by chance using the **Workgroup** secuirty model (.mdw) file, well mdw is mandatory in 2003 but if you have made any changes beyond the default then you will need to ensure you are using the same mdw file on the server.  Do you login under a different username for example and does the default **Admin** user have write access to the tables?

Comment: Hi Matt sorry for the late reply. I tried this on a different hosting site it just works fine. But the hosting which I am actually using it won't work. I have granted full access to the App_Data folder and I don't have any login username and no password.

Comment: Are you sure you have write access on that server, are you able to open a table and manually edit some data?